# Switching between perspectives in eclipse

Tags: java

I want to switch between workspaces(Package explorer, search, Java, Debug) in eclipse using something like Ctrl-PageUp Ctrl-PageDown.
I know that by pressing Ctrl-F7, you can acces a list, but I want it this way because it is faster. Can anyone help?

Sorry, when i was saying pressing Ctrl - F8, I actually mean Ctrl-F7

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4):

What you want to switch between is called perspectives, not workspaces. Open the properties and go to `General`->`Keys`. You can type `perspective` into the filter box to see all perspective related shortcuts you can define. Ther you'll see that  `Ctrl` + `F8` is `Next Perspective` already should already do what you want. You don't need to select in the menu. If you release the keys immediately, it always opens the next view. Use the same combination with `Shift` and you get the previous view.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to understand that, **View, Perspective & Workspace** are different terms & have different meanings. The examples & shortcut you've given point to Navigation of Views.

If you want to change the shortcut Key(s) for View Navigation, go to `Window --> Preferences --> General --> Keys`. Write `Ctrl + F7` in serach bar & you should get **Next View** command. Select it & change it **Bindings** to the key(s) you want to use as shortcut. & Then click on OK to save your settings.